# ASP.NET version of Joomla

Tags: asp.net, content-management-system, joomla

Does anyone ever found/used an ASP.NET application similar to Joomla?
I need to set up a quick and dirty CMS on a Windows Server and our client doesn't want us to use something else than ASP.NET.

Comment: pigeoncms is now available for download.
official site: [http://www.pigeoncms.com](http://www.pigeoncms.com)
or follow it on google code

Answer (score 5):

I've been told by a friend that [Umbraco](http://www.umbraco.org/) is everything you would ever want in a CMS (and it was in the list that Nathan included in his answer). This recommendation is coming from a guy who's built several CMS solutions over the years and after taking a brief look at it, I think I'm going to try to push my clients towards using it over their current solutions.

Comment: Is it as good as I heard Joomla is or is it any better?

Answer (score 3):

[DotNetNuke](http://www.dotnetnuke.com/) is quick to set up and get running.  It is the best ASP.NET CMS that I have used.

It comes with many modules, and can be extended with numerous commercial and free 3rd party modules.

It is very easy to change to look of a DNN site by simply changing the assigned skin, and many 3rd party skins are available as well.

[Warbeats.com](http://www.warbeats.com/) runs on DNN, and handles quite a bit of traffic.

Comment: Just a warning, DNN doesn't give you control over your markup. This makes it a really poor choice, IMO.

Answer (score 2):

Community Server is a very well built CMS for ASP.NET, a [free version is available](http://communityserver.com/get-it-now/express/).

Answer (score 2):

[Graffiti](http://graffiticms.com/) is Telligent's CMS (makers of the previously mentioned Community Server) and my be more appropriate depending on your requirements.

There are also many [CMS projects on Codeplex](http://www.codeplex.com/Project/ProjectDirectory.aspx?TagName=CMS).

Answer (score 2):

I tried Graffiti and DotNetNuke and thought both were troublesome, then I tried [Umbraco](http://www.umbraco.org/) based on a recommendation from a friend and I love it! So much that I recommended it to Kooshmoose... I should also note that dasBlog is not a CMS, it's just blog software (which I use on my personal site and love, but it's not a CMS...)

Answer (score 1):

Did you Look at DotNetNuke (http://www.dotnetnuke.com/) Its seems to be a good Systems to Start off as a base , But I doubt I could call it a Full CMS ? (Upto the users to decide)

Answer (score 1):

MojoPortal might be worth a look into. Other than that, the list linked to by Nathan is well-worth looking into

Answer (score 1):

[umbraco](http://www.umbraco.org/) gets my vote as a good CMS that comes close to Joomla in maturity and out of the box functionality.  I'm not that fond of DNN, but it's been at least a year since I ran it thru its paces.

Answer (score 1):

See also [Oxite](http://www.codeplex.com/oxite). It's an ASP.NET MVC Blog engine that you can use it for CMS.

Answer (score 1):

If the concern isn't really about the ASP.Net language but about keeping a Windows server, you can use [Joomla on IIS](http://www.microsoft.com/web/joomla/).

You can also check the [list of CMSs](http://www.microsoft.com/web/gallery/Categories.aspx?category=ContentMgmt) on [Microsoft's Web Platform](http://www.microsoft.com/web/)