# I would like to convert Joomla CMS to ASP.net as there is no CMS like Joomla in .net. Would that be a good idea?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, joomla

I have this idea boggling my head since a long time.

As a developer, I get a lot from the community and feel like giving back something to the community.

And after knowing and working on Joomla i found Joomla CMS as the most flexible, easy and user friendly cms.

As a developer, I like most of the features of it.

Now, i want to have a asp.net version of joomla, available free to the community.
I wanted to start it from scratch and it would be a copy/same as joomla.

Would that be a good idea to go with it?

Are there any CMS (same as Joomla) available in asp.net?

I would like to have suggestions and advice from my community developers.
Critics are welcomed ;)
SIA

Comment: Also, i have read this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5061/asp-net-version-of-joomla. Its talking about .net CMS but i am talking about JOOMLA.NET

Comment: If you want to make JOOMLA.NET, you must have a lot of spare time, propably few years. How many ASP.NET applications did you make?

Comment: Maybe using Phalanger to do the port will be quicker (not saying quick or worthwhile though - thats a different point)- www.codeplex.com/Phalanger - it's PHP language implementation for .Net as well as many of the default functions in PHP

Comment: I would recommend browsing through CodePlex (pretty much what Saret suggested). Creating a CMS is a crazy task. You'd probably be much better served just finding one that's up and running or one that gives you a good start at least. You may want to check out Telerik's Siteinfinity. They have a community edition that I believe is compatible w/ MVC, but definitely works w/ ASP .NET.

Answer (score 2):

Checkout [CMSWire](http://www.cmswire.com/cms/products/).  They have the language platform for most of the CMS packages along with a bunch of other attributes.

I think every web developer writes a CMS at some point in their career.  I'm working on one right now.  But a project the size of Joomla or Dotnetnuke is way too big for one person, even fulltime.

Btw, my favorite CMS ( based of demos ) that I've seen so for is [Umbraco](http://umbraco.org/).

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same idea as well but like people say it is a huge task.
However it's not as big as creating a CMS in a language like PHP from scratch becuase you can use features like rich data controls, Membership, profiles, themes, masterpages, webparts etc.

For that reason I would not een bother trying to convert joomla's php to c# but rather create a feature list and write code from that.

The only CMS that I've found comes close to joomla is Kentico mainly because of the use of webparts.

Comment: Somehow i see its do-able. because not now but after 6 months i will have a cms ready???  I can utilize my leasure time and start implementation, if my friends are interested i can allow them to join

Answer (score 1):

You might look at DOTNETNUKE (http://www.dotnetnuke.com/).

That is the only major .NET based CMS that I know of. I also use Joomla and have used DOTNETNUKE as well and they offer many of the same features. If .NET is the way you need to go, this is really the only .NET CMS Open Source player out there.

Comment: when i was very new to the cms, i tried using dotnetnuke and unable to do anything in it.  I know thats my fault.  But now i will reconsider it and give it a try.  

If there is a solution that is similar to joomla and can serve all the functionalities of joomla with friendly UI then I will have second thoughts.

Anyway thanks aeisenbe. :)